# Wordpress redirect all except my IP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ip, permalinks

I have two wordpress websites **NEW** and **OLD** with permalinks. The OLD website is locatet at `http://website.com/old` and the NEW is located at `http://website.com`.

I want to redirect all exept my IP to the OLD website (`http://website.com/old`) using .htaccess.

The default .htaccess located at the main directorie (`http://website.com`) is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've changed this to the following (where xx.xxx.x.xxx is my IP):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^xx.xxx.x.xxx
RewriteRule .* http://website.com/old [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

At this point I can redirect all to the OLD website exept my IP. The problem is when I navigate to any page on my NEW website like `http://website.com/contacts` it retuns:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /contacts/ was not found on this server.
Apache Server at website.com Port 80
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must keep Wordpress' main rule **after** your IP-check

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if not my ip then redirect to old version
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^xx\.xxx\.x\.xxx$
RewriteRule . old [R=302,L]

# if we're here, it means it's me so display new version
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```